# no using models in Cascading Dropdownlist mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, drop-down-menu

I have a controller that search the database values ​​from a column and put it in a DropDownList:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var listPro = db.P1_PRODUTOS.Select(c => new { c.id_produtos, c.sgl_produtos });
            ViewBag.Produtos = new SelectList(listPro.AsEnumerable(), "id_produtos", "sgl_produtos");


            return View();
        }
```

In View:

```
th>Produtos: @Html.DropDownList("Produtos", (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryId, "Selecione o Produto")</th>
```

Is functioning normally.

How do I enable another DropDownList, and put values ​​from another table in the database related to a choice of the first DropDownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check this
im doing that just now see my code 
$("#Container").on("change", "select", function () {
            var url = '/Controller/Action/Get';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                cache: true,
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'example': $('#example').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    var items = $('#Dropdown');
                    items.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, drdvalue) {
                        items.append(
                         $('<option/>', {
                             value: drdvalue.Text,
                             html: drdvalue.Value
                         })
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

you might need Ajax. 
have a look at the below 
http://tutsblog.net/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-based-on-another-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-using-json/

Comment: I'm having just one problem, I am unable to pass the value for Dropdown, this in response to the script below, could help me to see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm having just one problem, I am unable to pass the value for Dropdown,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Rod').change(function () { ChangeRod(); });
    });

    function ChangeRod() {
        var selectedValue = $('#Rod option:selected').val();
        if ($.trim(selectedValue).length > 0) {
            GetLevant(selectedValue);
        }
    }

    function GetLevant(id_Rod) {
        $.ajax(
       {
            url: '@Url.Action("Levant", "GraficosLevants")',
            data: { id_Rod: id_Rod },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            sucess: function (data)
            {
                if (data.length >= 0)
                {
                    $('#Levant').empty();
                    $('#Levant').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Selecione o Levant'));
                    $.each(data, function (i, item)
                    {
                        $('#Levant').append(('<option></option>').val(item.key).text(item.Value));
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

With the following class in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Levant(string id_Rod)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id_Rod))
            {
                var Levants = this.GetLevant(id_Rod);
                if (Levants.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var Levant in Levants)
                    {
                        items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Levant.id.ToString(), Levant.Levant));
                    }
                }

            }
            return this.Json(items);
        }



        private IEnumerable<XXX_Levant> GetLevant(string id_Rod)
        {
            int idSelectRod = Convert.ToInt32(id_Rod);
            var query = db.XXX_Levant.Where(l => l.Rod_id == idSelectRod).OrderBy(l => l.Levant);
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: try: 
'id_Rod': id_Rod

Comment: I do not understand where to put it try: 'id_Rod': id_Rod

Comment: data: { 'id_Rod': id_Rod },